# DirectionsService - OVER_QUERY_LIMIT after 3 request?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code :

```
function traceRoute(part, arr) {
    var polylineTrattaTreno = new Array();
    var request = {
        origin: part,
        destination: arr,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            ... manage my data
        } else {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
}
```

and I noticed that if I call this function 3 times, all is ok! Than I always get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`. Tried on putting timeout of 1 or 2 seconds. But nothing happens. Seems that I can't do more than 3 request for time?

Comment: Are you calling this function recursively in a forloop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits)-

> Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500
>   directions requests per day. Each directions search will count as a
>   single request against your daily quota when the mode of
>   transportation is driving, walking or cycling. Searching for **transit**
>   directions will count as 4 requests.

Adding to it-

> Additionally, note that Directions API URLs are restricted to 2048
>   characters, before URL Encoding. As some Directions service URLs may
>   involve many locations along a path, be aware of this limit when
>   constructing your URLs.

Your origin and destination values might be quite distant and also considering the fact you are using transit direction, causing the limit being reached soon.

**Update-** If you set the mode to "transit" you must also specify either a departure_time or an arrival_time.

Comment: So "transit" is limited at 4 request for time? :O

Comment: It is counted as 4 requests when you do a single transit directions search. However doing 3 requests as you stated shouldn't reach the limit. You may also need to see the length of your url as per the second paragh.

Comment: Also are you experiencing it for a 24hr time period or is it for a few seconds? There are two kinds of limits- short term and long term(24hr).

Comment: It's the same...since many days! Which url do you mean? How can I check it? The request uri to the server google api? :O

Comment: A small update added to answer. You dint tell whether you are facing the error for 24hr's or for seconds? May be the seconds limit can be overcome by setting more time interval between simultaneous requests.

Comment: It happens everytime this error, not after 24 hour! I tried with (also) 10 seconds, but it doesnt change...